# Can we say "a piece of equipment turns on/off"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Most dictionaries say "**turn**" is a transitive verb in "**turn something <-> on/off**".
For example, "**I turned the hair dryer on/off**"

Can "**turn**" in this case is an intransitive verb?

Can we say "**a piece of equipment turns on/off**"?

For example, "*I dropped the hair dryer (which is plugged in) and it happened to turn on*"?

Other phrases that we can use are "**come/go on**" or "**start working**".

But "*I dropped the hair dryer (which is plugged in) and it happened to go/come on*" or "...it happened to start working" don't sound good.

Comment: Yes, appliances, e.g. computers, video recorders, can turn on or off by themselves, e.g. at a selected time.

Comment: (Since the sentence is in the past tense you need _which was plugged in_ or _while it was plugged in_.) I was going to say the opposite to Michael - _come on_ or _turn itself on_ sound more natural to me.

Comment: @KateBunting - 'Why does my computer/TV/phone/car radio turn on by itself?' seems to be a very common query on Google (faulty remote, timer set and forgotten, loose power connection etc). I think that 'come on' vs 'turn on' might be a US/UK thing. People of a certain age and above might remember Timothy Leary's exhortation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which dictionaries you're using, but M-W lists intransitive senses for both ["turn on"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20on) and ["turn off"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20off). It also includes an intransitive definition for ["turn"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn) that is relevant:

> b(1): to pass from one state to another : CHANGE
> // water had *turned* to ice

The following would be perfectly fine, for example:

> My house lights turn on at 8:00 pm every night.
> The dishwasher turned off by itself.